# Interior trim damage repair or replace?

Tags: drywall, trim

My lovely husky decided to “renovate” some of our interior trim when he was younger. Some of it seems like it could be repaired, while other portions probably need to be replaced. What do you think is the best course of action?

[image]     [image]

[image]

Comment: searching this site for `repair trim dog` only turned up 3 responses, but `repair trim` turns up dozens of questions that have been asked about this. Have you looked through those? Now that you've got a list of possibilities, it's up to you to determine which is "best" for you because we don't know what your definition of "best" is and it _will_ be different than other people's definitions. That's why "best" questions are considered off-topic, opinion based questions. If those other questions still leave you wondering, please [edit] to indicate where you're still undecided.